# How to relocate images

Tags: categories, images, migration

I need to move all images attached to posts of a specific category (MyCat) from its current standard location (/uploads/year/month/) to a specific category folder (/uploads/mycat/).

For instance:

```
/uploads/2015/06/mycat-post1-image1.jpg
/uploads/2015/06/mycat-post1-image2.jpg
/uploads/2015/07/mycat-post2-image3.jpg
/uploads/2015/08/mycat-post3-image4.jpg
```

... and much more mycat images ...

move to...

```
/uploads/mycat/image1.jpg
/uploads/mycat/image2.jpg
/uploads/mycat/image3.jpg
/uploads/mycat/image4.jpg
```

(not necessary renaming, just for illustrating).

I need to physically move the images from source folders to target one, and also need to change the links in database. But, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to code an external program, I can't see any other way. I used Java JDBC in my case.

Query:

```
SELECT p.post_title, m.meta_value
FROM wp_term_taxonomy tt
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr on tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
inner join wp_posts p on p.ID = tr.object_id
inner join wp_posts p2 on p.ID = p2.post_parent
inner join wp_postmeta m on p2.ID = m.post_id
where tt.term_id = 795
and p.post_status = 'publish'
and p.post_type = 'post'
and p2.post_type='attachment' and p2.post_status = 'inherit'
and m.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
```

But was not able to copy to a specific mycat, wordpress does not recognize custom folder structure for media.

Then, as all images are in current year/month, I did:

```
UPDATE wp_posts p
SET p.post_content = REPLACE(p.post_content, 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/', 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/'),
p.post_content = REPLACE(p.post_content, 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/', 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/'),
p.post_content = REPLACE(p.post_content, 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/', 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/'),
p.post_content = REPLACE(p.post_content, 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/', 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/'),
p.post_content = REPLACE(p.post_content, 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/', 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/'),
p.post_content = REPLACE(p.post_content, 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/', 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/'),
p.post_content = REPLACE(p.post_content, 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/', 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/'),
p.post_content = REPLACE(p.post_content, 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/', 'http://miwp.local/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/')
WHERE p.post_name LIKE 'mycat-%';
```

provided post_name is prefixed with 'mycat-' .